# public access methods inside a default access class.. what is the point?

Tags: java, access-modifiers

What does it mean if you make a class default access, and mark a method contained in that class public?  In other words, how can you have public access to a method if the enclosing class is not accessible publicly?

Comment: Maybe through an [abstract factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) or [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) used to create instances.

Comment: Low quality question : [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: @afzalex,  Please don't make such gratuitous remarks like 'Low quality question' before answering the question.. Look at the other posts, people have actually given meaningful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping the methods public may be required in certain cases, for example, when your class with default access implements a public interface.

This is useful when your API is defined in terms of interfaces, and your default-access class implements one of these public interfaces. Users of your API can instantiate your default-access class through factory methods.

Comment: you pointed out a very interesting thing. I didn't think of that. Thanks.

Comment: One more question.. Is this the only situation where  it makes sense to declare a public method in a default access class?

Comment: @user3516726 This is the most common case, and the only one where it is strictly required (I count implementing public abstract and non-abstract classes in this category, too). Other cases do not strictly require public methods, but you may choose to do it anyway to highlight to people who maintain your code after you that these methods are intended fir use by anyone who has access to this class.

Comment: Thank you. That clarifies it.

Answer (score 2):

`public` is often needed when you override some public methods or implements `interface`s.
Let's take the simple example of the Object#equals method.

Although your main class would have **default scope**, you cannot override the method while reducing the visibilty. 
So you will need:  `public void equals(.......`

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like that:

```
package p1;
class C1 {
    public void publicMethod() {}
}
```

In another package:

```
package p2;
import p1.C1; // not allowed
public class C2 {
    C1 c1; // not allowed
    void test() {
        c1.publicMethod(); // not allowed
    }
}
```

In case of inheritance, the `publicMethod` can be used:

```
package p1;
public class C2 extends C1 {}
```

Now the `publicMethod` can be access:

```
package p2;
import p1.C2; // C2 is public, ok !
public class C3 {
    C2 c2;  // C2 is public, ok !
    void test() {
        c2.publicMethod(); // C2 is public, use publicMethod of C1 !
    }
}
```

So, reduce a `class` visibility can be usefull for kind of abtract class that should not be used directly outside the package.

Comment: You have said 'In case of inheritance the publicMethod can be used'. But if the class is declared default access, no method in it (even public) can be accessed outside the package. In fact, outside the package, you cannot even subclass a class with default access.

Comment: p1.C2 (public) extends p1.C1 (default). p1.C2 instance can access to public method of p1.C1 in any package. Try yourself.

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding. What I am saying is that a default access method can be invoked only from inside the package, not outside. If you have a 'protected' access method, then it can be invoked by a subclass even from outside the package.

Comment: @user3516726 I agree, default access for method is accessible to package classes only. The current question is "default access for classes, not for methods".

Comment: If a class has default access: 1. you cannot instantiate it from another package. So none of its instance methods are available outside its package. 2. None of its static methods can be invoked from another package.   Correct?

Comment: Yes. For `static` it's clear. If a subclass of the same package is public, the public methods are accessibles, like my sample.